# Editor Opens main.dart on Save

Tags: android-studio, flutter-web

Have a flutter web project being developed using Android Studio and something has changed recently which is now causing Android Studio to open up the file `main.dart` in the editor pane whenever a file is saved while the project is running in chrome.

Say the project is made up of two dart files: `main.dart` and `example.dart` and I have only the file `example.dart` open in the editor. I then click `run 'main.dart` which causes the application to launch in chrome browser. If I then make a change in `example.dart` while the app is running and save the file, the `main.dart` file is automatically opened in Android Studio's editor pane and gets the focus. This is forcing me to have to switch back to the `example.dart` file each time I want to make another change to it.

Not sure if it is Android Studio doing this or flutter itself as part of its hot reload functionality. Or maybe something I clicked on by mistake making it do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did a flutter upgrade and the issue has now gone away so maybe the problem was somewhere in flutter web's Hot Reload functionality.